# Clicking on Bootstrap navbar toggle button is not displaying collapsed content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a responsive navbar using Bootstrap. When I click on the toggler icon on extra-small and small screen sizes, I don't see the collapsed content. What's the problem? The following is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=n">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
    <title>MONGO DB</title>
</head>
<body>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">mongoDB</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">

                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Cloud</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Software</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Learn</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav fourth">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Solutions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Docs</a></li>
                    </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the problem is with Jquery library that you used, replace it with <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> and test the code, I am also put you code on jsfiddle and its work https://jsfiddle.net/51j0xr3c/.

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Copy paste the code from jsfiddle and check it out, maybe the problem is with bootstrap version replace both bootstrap css and js with  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous"> and <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>